# Piranha CMS Custom Menus

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, piranha-cms

I was able to add tabs but by default all the tabs get selected. I have 3 tabs below My Custom Menu. All three get selected. I have given SelectedActions only to one of the tab. Why does this happen?

I have taken code from [here](http://piranhacms.org/docs/extend/manager-menu).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't specify `SelectedActions` it assumes that **all** actions for the specified controller are valid. So if all of your tabs are related to the same controller they could very well get selected at the same time.